# System.IO.FileNotFoundException Google.GData.Spreadsheets

Tags: c#, api, filenotfoundexception

I have spent countless hours on the web trying to figure out how to solve this error, but I could not understand it at all.

What I have is a simple console application that retrieves a list of Spreadsheets on a certain Google Spreadsheets account.

It works flawlessly on my own pc, but when I transfer it to another pc to test it, I get the following error message and the program crashes:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or asssembly ´Google.GData.Spreadsheets, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3f77feb76ff0d9a1´ or one of its dependencies. File not found. at Wolfscape_Test.Program.Main<String[] args>
```

I added the .dll references in my project and installed the Google Spreadsheet API on the other PC, then built the program and sent the exe over to the other pc.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Spreadsheets;

namespace Wolfscape_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("WolfscapeDummy");
            service.setUserCredentials("mymail@gmail.com", "myPassword");

            SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();

            // Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
            SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.Query(query);

            // Loop through all spreadsheets
            foreach (SpreadsheetEntry entry in feed.Entries)
            {
                // Print the title of this spreadsheet to the screen
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Title.Text);
            }

        Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make this work on another pc?

Comment: did you add the reference to the following assemblies in the reference node also is it being copied over to the bin directory on the other machine.. set the `copy local=` property to `true` 
`using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Spreadsheets;` make sure you have the proper references added to the project reference node as well

Comment: I added references according to this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx


Copy local is already set to true, and exported together with the project.
I have tried using the .dll files in the same folder as the program, as well as a separate folder called "refs", but still the same result.

Comment: I think I solved it by adding the reference folder in my project settings. Sorry for taking your time, but thanks for helping!

Comment: If you solved it either answer your own question or remove it but don't put words like *solved* in the title. That is **NOT** how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Pardon, everything works differently.
Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by adding a reference folder in my project settings.